# Object class comes twice in prototype chain of DOMWindow?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, prototype, prototype-chain

Why do we have 2 class Object and again Object in prototype chain of window?

window --> DOMWindow --->Object --->Object ---> null

Can anyone please give me some point about this design?

Follwing is the output on chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: *The `DOMWindow` as shown in the console is a result of the smart Dev Tools: The constructors name is shown in this case. When you explicitly use `window.__proto__.toString()`, `[object Object]` would be shown three times.*

### Note about the design

To answer your question about the design, I cite the [ES5 specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4) (emphasis is mine):

> All objects have an internal property called `[[Prototype]]`. The value
>   of this property is either null or an object and is used for
>   implementing inheritance. Whether or not a native object can have a
>   host object as its `[[Prototype]]` depends on the implementation. **Every
>   `[[Prototype]]` chain must have finite length (that is, starting from
>   any object, recursively accessing the `[[Prototype]]` internal property
>   must eventually lead to a `null` value).**

So, it's not weird that you see `null` in the end.

### More details

Some (technical) notes beforehand:

- [`Object.getPrototypeOf( obj )`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.2) returns the [`[[Prototype]]`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.2) property of an object `obj`.
- The [`[[Class]]`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.2) property of an object represents its internal class. Its name can be extracted using `Object.prototype.toString.call( obj )`.

Table:

```
   toString() result:   [[Class]]   #  Additional notes
1. [object DOMWindow]    global     # The global object
2. [object Object]       Object     # [[Prototype]] of the Global object
3. [object Object]       Object     # [[Prototype]] of 2 (dummy?)
4. [object Object]       Object     # [[Prototype]] of 3 === Object.prototype
5. [object Null]         Null       # Object.prototype.__proto__ === null
```

1. The [global object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1).
   Examples: `window` in browser-JavaScript, `global` in [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).
2. According to [section 15.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1), the `[[Prototype]]` and `[[Class]]` properties of `global` are implementation-dependent. In Chrome, the implementation of `DOMWindow` looks like the one as described in [this IDL](http://code.google.com/p/webcl/source/browse/trunk/Source/WebCore/page/DOMWindow.idl).
3. In Chrome, this constructor has literally no name. In Firefox, this is the `Global Scope Polluter` class.
   **This seems to be a dummy object, hence the lack of properties.**
4. The previous object is a true instance of `Object`.
   **This explains the logged `__defineGetter`, etc. properties in the console.**
5. The `[[Prototype]]` property of `Object.prototype` is `null`, see [section 15.2.4](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4).

### Additional references

- Code to get the `[[Class]]` properties:

  ```
  var w = window;
  while (1) {
      console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(w));
      if (w == null) break;
      w = Object.getPrototypeOf(w);
  }
  ```
- [15.1 - The Global Object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1)
- [15.2.4 - Properties of the Object Prototype Object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4)
- [WebCore](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/WebKit#WebCore)'s [`DOMWindow.idl`](http://code.google.com/p/webcl/source/browse/trunk/Source/WebCore/page/DOMWindow.idl) <sup>What is an [Interface definition language](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-WebIDL-20120207/#idl)?</sup> for `DOMWindow` (AFAIK, it's *not* V8s IDL, because V8's constructors are not postfixed with `Constructor`).